# Mongodb replication slave stuck at STARTUP2

Tags: mongodb

I have a two member mongo replication set. Authentication is enabled through keyfile. The problem is the slave gets stuck in STARTUP2 state and does not move further. Seems like the sync starts and then it complains about not finding a member to sync from. What could be the problem here?
Also am not able to connect to the mongo shell on the slave, its stuck as well.

Logs from the primary

```
2016-06-08T01:04:38.023+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-06-08T01:04:38.044+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=43288 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=test-mongo1
2016-06-08T01:04:38.044+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
2016-06-08T01:04:38.044+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7
2016-06-08T01:04:38.044+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2016-06-08T01:04:38.044+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-06-08T01:04:38.044+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-06-08T01:04:38.044+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-06-08T01:04:38.045+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2016-06-08T01:04:38.045+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-06-08T01:04:38.045+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-06-08T01:04:38.045+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27017 }, operationProfiling: { mode: "all" }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, replication: { replSetName: "some_name" }, security: { keyFile: "/etc/mongodb-keyfile" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-06-08T01:04:38.066+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-06-08T01:04:38.066+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-06-08T01:04:38.613+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Starting WiredTigerRecordStoreThread local.oplog.rs
2016-06-08T01:04:38.613+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 7 records totaling to 1275 bytes
2016-06-08T01:04:38.613+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Scanning the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
2016-06-08T01:04:38.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-08T01:04:38.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-06-08T01:04:38.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-06-08T01:04:38.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-08T01:04:38.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 4096 processes, 64000 files. Number of processes should be at least 32000 : 0.5 times number of files.
2016-06-08T01:04:38.667+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-06-08T01:04:38.670+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data'
2016-06-08T01:04:38.670+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-06-08T01:04:38.686+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-06-08T01:04:38.689+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] New replica set config in use: { _id: "some_name", version: 1, protocolVersion: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "test-mongo1:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 } } }
2016-06-08T01:04:38.689+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] This node is test-mongo1:27017 in the config
2016-06-08T01:04:38.689+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to STARTUP2
2016-06-08T01:04:38.690+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to SECONDARY
2016-06-08T01:04:38.690+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected
2016-06-08T01:04:38.690+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] dry election run succeeded, running for election
2016-06-08T01:04:38.690+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] election succeeded, assuming primary role in term 2
2016-06-08T01:04:38.690+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to PRIMARY
2016-06-08T01:04:38.690+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] transition to primary complete; database writes are now permitted
2016-06-08T01:04:50.480+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45877 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-06-08T01:04:50.496+0000 I ACCESS   [conn1] Successfully authenticated as principal admin on admin
2016-06-08T01:04:50.497+0000 I REPL     [conn1] replSetReconfig admin command received from client
2016-06-08T01:04:50.522+0000 I REPL     [conn1] replSetReconfig config object with 2 members parses ok
2016-06-08T01:04:50.545+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to 10.3.0.14:27017
2016-06-08T01:04:50.546+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] New replica set config in use: { _id: "some_name", version: 2, protocolVersion: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "test-mongo1:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 }, { _id: 1, host: "10.3.0.14:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 } } }
2016-06-08T01:04:50.546+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] This node is test-mongo1:27017 in the config
```

Logs from slave

```
2016-06-08T01:04:38.661+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data'
2016-06-08T01:04:38.661+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-06-08T01:04:38.661+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-06-08T01:04:50.503+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.3.0.13:32897 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-06-08T01:04:50.520+0000 I ACCESS   [conn1] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
2016-06-08T01:04:50.523+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 10.3.0.13:32897 (0 connections now open)
2016-06-08T01:04:50.524+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.3.0.13:32898 #2 (1 connection now open)
2016-06-08T01:04:50.545+0000 I ACCESS   [conn2] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local
2016-06-08T01:04:50.584+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Successfully connected to test-mongo1:27017
2016-06-08T01:04:50.713+0000 I REPL     [replExecDBWorker-0] Starting replication applier threads
2016-06-08T01:04:50.713+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] New replica set config in use: { _id: "some_name", version: 2, protocolVersion: 1, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "test-mongo1:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 }, { _id: 1, host: "10.3.0.14:27017", arbiterOnly: false, buildIndexes: true, hidden: false, priority: 1.0, tags: {}, slaveDelay: 0, votes: 1 } ], settings: { chainingAllowed: true, heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000, heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10, electionTimeoutMillis: 10000, getLastErrorModes: {}, getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 } } }
2016-06-08T01:04:50.713+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] This node is 10.3.0.14:27017 in the config
2016-06-08T01:04:50.713+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to STARTUP2
2016-06-08T01:04:50.714+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] ******
2016-06-08T01:04:50.714+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] creating replication oplog of size: 1336MB...
2016-06-08T01:04:50.714+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member test-mongo1:27017 is now in state PRIMARY
2016-06-08T01:04:50.771+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] Starting WiredTigerRecordStoreThread local.oplog.rs
2016-06-08T01:04:50.771+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] The size storer reports that the oplog contains 0 records totaling to 0 bytes
2016-06-08T01:04:50.771+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] Scanning the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation
2016-06-08T01:04:51.286+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] ******
2016-06-08T01:04:51.286+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync pending
2016-06-08T01:04:51.398+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: test-mongo1:27017
2016-06-08T01:04:51.974+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync drop all databases
2016-06-08T01:04:51.974+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] dropAllDatabasesExceptLocal 1
2016-06-08T01:04:51.974+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync clone all databases
2016-06-08T01:04:51.975+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning db: admin
2016-06-08T01:04:52.224+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync] build index on: admin.system.users properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.users" }
2016-06-08T01:04:52.224+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync]         building index using bulk method
2016-06-08T01:04:52.260+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync] build index done.  scanned 2 total records. 0 secs
2016-06-08T01:04:52.380+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 1, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2016-06-08T01:04:52.380+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync]         building index using bulk method
2016-06-08T01:04:52.402+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync] build index done.  scanned 1 total records. 0 secs
2016-06-08T01:04:52.403+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync data copy, starting syncup
2016-06-08T01:04:52.403+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] oplog sync 1 of 3
2016-06-08T01:04:52.404+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] oplog sync 2 of 3
2016-06-08T01:04:52.405+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync building indexes
2016-06-08T01:04:52.405+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync cloning indexes for : admin
2016-06-08T01:04:52.427+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] copying indexes for: { name: "system.users", options: {} }
2016-06-08T01:04:52.521+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync] build index on: admin.system.users properties: { v: 1, unique: true, key: { user: 1, db: 1 }, name: "user_1_db_1", ns: "admin.system.users" }
2016-06-08T01:04:52.521+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync]         building index using bulk method
2016-06-08T01:04:52.543+0000 I INDEX    [rsSync] build index done.  scanned 2 total records. 0 secs
2016-06-08T01:04:52.543+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] copying indexes for: { name: "system.version", options: {} }
2016-06-08T01:04:52.544+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] oplog sync 3 of 3
2016-06-08T01:04:52.545+0000 I -        [rsSync] Creating profile collection: admin.system.profile
2016-06-08T01:04:52.715+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] could not find member to sync from
```

Configuration

```
# mongod.conf

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
 #bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


security:
  keyFile: /etc/mongodb-keyfile

operationProfiling:
  mode: all

replication:
  replSetName: somename

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: could you show us configuration? btw try to rebuild it in different data and log directory

Comment: `could not find member to sync from` -- this could be config issue

Comment: @profesor79 have added configuration file for reference

Comment: and other system is runnind in diffrent box with same config?

Comment: @profesor79 yes, exact same config

Comment: @dnivra had the same issue, In my case it looked like mongo is choked because of foreground indexing.